# A singular boundary value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, singularity-theory, boundary-value-problem

Is there any numerical approach to solve a BVPs for ODEs of the form:
$y'=\frac{ky^2-y^{3/2}-y}{\beta t}$ with initial point $(0,y0)$?

I know a problem of the form $y' = \frac{S}{t}y+f(t,y)$ with singularity at the initial point can be solved numerically, but does a problem like mine can be solved?

Comment: You realize of course that the equation is separable and that there is a straightforward analytical solution.

Comment: Yes, I know, but as $ln(t)$ evaluates to $-\infty$ at initial point, I can not get the constant term.

Comment: Actually your IVP is not defined at $t=0$ even if it has $y=y_0=$ constant (steady state) solution. That's why you dont find a value of constant integration using your initial condition.